# Python: Get Argparse.parseargs as Raw String

Tags: python, string, path, command-line-arguments

When I try to use `argparse.parseargs()` by printing it (for example), it always returns `Namespace(argName='String Content')`
So, if I get returned that I can't use it for other functions, for working with path (in my case).
So, there is a way to only get returned just the string being raw (for working with Windows paths, in my case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_args()` returns a collection of values, (roughly) one for each argument you define. That doesn't change just because you only define one argument. Just extract the value you want.

```
p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--argName', default="foo")
args = p.parse_args()

print(args.argName)
```